# How is the default configuration of the Spring Boot health endpoint useful

Tags: spring-boot, health-monitoring

Spring Boot can provide a [*health endpoint*](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html). That is an HTTP URI (`/actuator/health`, by default) you can GET for [health information](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/actuator-api/html/#health) about the application. Spring Boot enables this functionality by default. Spring Boot also has a configuration property, `management.endpoint.health.show-details`, for securing whether details are included in the response. The default value of that property is `never`, so details are not shown. Therefore the default configuration of Spring Boot is to provide the endpoint, but without any details.

But what is the use of a health endpoint without details? What does being able to GET the resource tell you, despite the resource containing no details?

Comment: By getting a 200 response containing a json object with the value ”UP” is useful för saap’s like openshift kubernetes to poll your seevice nd know that it is alive and working. The endpoint also tells you by responding with a 200 that it has even started. So there are many usercases for production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `management.endpoint.health.show-details=never`, you can still see the aggregated status. This status is an aggregation of all detail statuses. By default, the `OrderedHealthAggregator` is being used, which results in:

- If all details are `UP`, the parent is also `UP`
- If one of the details is `DOWN`, the parent is also `DOWN`

This is the relevant part of [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-health):

> By default, the final system state is derived by the `HealthAggregator` which sorts the statuses from each `HealthIndicator` based on an ordered list of statuses. The first status in the sorted list is used as the overall health status. If no `HealthIndicator` returns a status that is known to the `HealthAggregator`, an `UNKNOWN` status is used.

The order can be configured through the `management.health.status.order` property. By default it contains `DOWN, OUT_OF_SERVICE, UNKNOWN, UP`.

The HTTP status also changes depending on the aggregate status. Both `UP` and `UNKNOWN` result in a HTTP status 200, while `DOWN` and `OUT_OF_SERVICE` result in an HTTP status 503. This is the relevant part of [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#_writing_custom_healthindicators):

> The HTTP status code in the response reflects the overall health status (for example, `UP` maps to 200, while `OUT_OF_SERVICE` and `DOWN` map to 503).

You can also configure which HTTP status should be picked, for example by configuring `management.health.status.http-mapping.DOWN=418`.

This means that you can still use that piece of information to know whether or not something is wrong. This can be useful for any tool/software that monitors these endpoints (Eureka, Kubernetes, any monitoring tool, ...).

You may wonder, why not show all detailed information by default? Well, the issue is that this can contain sensitive information, such as how much disk space you have, where your application configuration is stored, what types of database you connect to, ... .

Comment: There is no such thing as "FATAL" for health status. You can check all provided status in org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.Status class which are : DOWN, OUT_OF_SERVICE, UNKNOWN, UP

Comment: @Fabien You're right, I edited my answer to fix it.